# draw common zero-line in plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I use `plotly.js` lib to plot data on my web-service, and I have one question,
is it possible to make plot with common zero-line of two different y-scales. For example:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: so, i found answer, we can just use yaxis range:

Comment: for example yaxis1: {range: [-max(y1), max(y1)]} , yaxis2: {range: [-max(y2), max(y2)]

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, that sounds awesome! Would you please post it as an answer for your question?